# Using loop to create elements in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Based on  the next working code:

```
var myfields = new Array('id', 'firstName', 'lastName')

const usersd = users;   


ReactDOM.render(
<BootstrapTable data={usersd} search={true} cellEdit={ cellEditProp } height='480px' scrollTop={ 'Bottom' } pagination={true}  multiColumnSearch={ true } >
    <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField={myfields[0]} width='10' dataAlign='left'>{myfields[0]}</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField={myfields[1]} dataSort={ true } width='15' dataAlign='left' headerAlign='left'>{myfields[1]}</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField={myfields[2]} dataSort={ true }  width='15' dataAlign='left' headerAlign='left'>{myfields[2]}</TableHeaderColumn>
</BootstrapTable>,
document.getElementById('usersModTable')
);
```

I wanted to use a loop on those react commands that use an index. So I could use a loop like in:

```
var myfields = new Array('id', 'firstName', 'lastName')

const usersd = users;



ReactDOM.render(
<BootstrapTable data={usersd} search={true} cellEdit={ cellEditProp } height='480px' scrollTop={ 'Bottom' } pagination={true}  multiColumnSearch={ true } >
    <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField={myfields[0]} width='10' dataAlign='left'>{myfields[0]}</TableHeaderColumn>

    for(var i = 1;i<myfields.length;i++) {
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField={myfields[i]} dataSort={ true } width='15' dataAlign='left' headerAlign='left'>{myfields[i]}</TableHeaderColumn>           
    }

</BootstrapTable>, document.getElementById('usersModTable')
);
```

So far this loop doesn't work, but, is there a working way to do something like  this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code proposed by **Mayank Shukla** is a pretty way to get what you want (I would do it in the same way). But if what you are looking for is to use loops, the way should be more or less like this:

```
var myfields = new Array('id', 'firstName', 'lastName')

const usersd = users;

let components = [];
for(var i = 1;i<myfields.length;i++) {
    components.push(<TableHeaderColumn dataField={myfields[i]} dataSort={ true } width='15' dataAlign='left' headerAlign='left'>{myfields[i]}</TableHeaderColumn>);
}

ReactDOM.render(
<BootstrapTable data={usersd} search={true} cellEdit={ cellEditProp } height='480px' scrollTop={ 'Bottom' } pagination={true}  multiColumnSearch={ true } >
    <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField={myfields[0]} width='10' dataAlign='left'>{myfields[0]}</TableHeaderColumn>
    //for(var i = 1;i<myfields.length;i++) {
    //  <TableHeaderColumn dataField={myfields[i]} dataSort={ true } width='15' dataAlign='left' headerAlign='left'>{myfields[i]}</TableHeaderColumn>;
    //}
    {components}
</BootstrapTable>, document.getElementById('usersModTable')
);
```

or

```
var myfields = new Array('id', 'firstName', 'lastName')

const usersd = users;

ReactDOM.render(
<BootstrapTable data={usersd} search={true} cellEdit={ cellEditProp } height='480px' scrollTop={ 'Bottom' } pagination={true}  multiColumnSearch={ true } >
    <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField={myfields[0]} width='10' dataAlign='left'>{myfields[0]}</TableHeaderColumn>
    {
        let components = [];
        for(var i = 1;i<myfields.length;i++) {
            components.push(<TableHeaderColumn dataField={myfields[i]} dataSort={ true } width='15' dataAlign='left' headerAlign='left'>{myfields[i]}</TableHeaderColumn>);
        }
        return components;
    }
</BootstrapTable>, document.getElementById('usersModTable')
);
```

Answer (score 4):

First thing is, you forgot to use `{}`, if you are using any `js` code inside `html` element you need to use `{}`.

You are using the `loop` in a wrong way, `for` loop will not `return` anything, it is used just to iterate the `array`. Use `map` for this, it will return the `TableHeaderColumn` for each element. Like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BootstrapTable data={usersd} search={true} cellEdit={ cellEditProp } height='480px' scrollTop={ 'Bottom' } pagination={true}  multiColumnSearch={ true } >
        <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField={myfields[0]} width='10' dataAlign='left'>{myfields[0]}</TableHeaderColumn>

       {
          myfields.map((el, i) => <TableHeaderColumn
                                      key={i} 
                                      dataField={el}  
                                      dataSort={ true } 
                                      width='15' 
                                      dataAlign='left' 
                                      headerAlign='left'>
                                      {el}
                                  </TableHeaderColumn> 

       }

   </BootstrapTable>, document.getElementById('usersModTable'));
```

Check this example, **how to use `map` inside `jsx`**:

```js
var App = () => {
   return (
      <div>
          {
            [1,2,3,4].map(el => <p key={el} > {el} </p>)
          }
      </div>
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: Should not the code "return" the result of map function? Like `return array.map`...

Comment: no, `map` will `return` an `array` (its a property of `map`, it `return` an `array` of all the element that you returned from the body of `map`), that `array` will get rendered inside `jsx`, return is not required, is it not working ?

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca check the updated answer, how to use `map` inside `jsx`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things that you need to pay attention at while working in react - JSX to be specific. Let me walk you through your code.

```
ReactDOM.render(
// JSX starts here
<BootstrapTable data={usersd} search={true} cellEdit={ cellEditProp } height='480px' scrollTop={ 'Bottom' } pagination={true}  multiColumnSearch={ true } >
    <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField={myfields[0]} width='10' dataAlign='left'>{myfields[0]}</TableHeaderColumn>
    for(var i = 1;i<myfields.length;i++) {
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField={myfields[i]} dataSort={ true } width='15' dataAlign='left' headerAlign='left'>{myfields[i]}</TableHeaderColumn>           
    }
    {
      // You can write javascript code here. However you need to ensure that this will return a react/html component.
     someCondition ?
     <span>positive</span> :
     <span>negative</span>
    }
    {
     // Now might will notice that the for loop that you have used above, doesnt return a valid JSX. To overcome that you need to use the *map* to iterate and return the jsx.
     myfields.map(function() {
      return <TableHeaderColumn dataField={myfields[i]} dataSort={ true } width='15' dataAlign='left' headerAlign='left'>{myfields[i]}</TableHeaderColumn>
     })
    }
</BootstrapTable>
// JSX ends here
, document.getElementById('usersModTable')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

All the ideas you gave me are very interesting and very helpful. Given the nature of BootstrapTable I had to do:

```
var myfields = new Array('id', 'firstName', 'lastName')

const usersd = users;

let components = [<TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField={myfields[0]} width='10' dataAlign='left'>{myfields[0]}</TableHeaderColumn>];

for(var i = 1; i<myfields.length; i++) {
    components.push(<TableHeaderColumn dataField={myfields[i]} dataSort={ true } width='15' dataAlign='left' headerAlign='left'>{myfields[i]}</TableHeaderColumn>);
}

ReactDOM.render(
<BootstrapTable data={usersd} search={true} cellEdit={ cellEditProp } height='480px' scrollTop={ 'Bottom' } pagination={true}  multiColumnSearch={ true } >     

    {components}

</BootstrapTable>,
document.getElementById('usersModTable')
);
```

placing the first "isKey" component in the array and adding the others as Facundo La Roca mentioned. Thanks!!!